# How can I realize "sticky" collision, i.e. that objects connect as soon as they touch?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I'm fairly new to Blender (great piece of software btw), so please bare with me.

I'd like to have multiple spheres (up to 50), which move randomly in space and as soon as two spheres collide they should stick to each other and move on together.

How would you approach that problem? I already tried to make the spheres rigid bodies and set the friction parameters insanely high, but it did not work. I also tried to use lennard-jones force fields (I also cranked up the strength fairly high), but that did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried Metaballs as the particles?

Comment: @rob I have. However Metaballs will only make the spheres connect optically, but not physically. I.e. when two spheres move on after a collision, they will not stick to each other, but separate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the free molecular script Add-on. here is a tutorial on how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haS3B6q82kY

Comment: Thank you very much! That should do the trick.